# How to get distances in pyspark?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, geospatial, azure-databricks

I have a table like the following:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|                  ID|               point|          timestamp|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|679ac975acc4bdec9...|POINT (-73.267631...|2020-01-01 17:10:49|
|679ac975acc4bdec9...|POINT (-73.271446...|2020-01-01 02:12:31|
|679ac975acc4bdec9...|POINT (-73.265991...|2020-01-01 17:10:40|
|679ac975acc4bdec9...|POINT (-73.271446...|2020-01-01 02:54:15|
|679ac975acc4bdec9...|POINT (-73.265609...|2020-01-01 17:10:24|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I want to compute the distance between all the points but I am not able to do it.

However I can compute the distance from each point in the comlumn `point` to a specific point in the following way

```
distances = spark.sql(
    """
        SELECT ID, timestamp, point,
        ST_Distance(point, ST_PointFromText('-74.00672149658203, 40.73177719116211', ',')) as distance
        FROM myTable
    """).show(5)



+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|                  ID|          timestamp|               point|          distance|
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|679ac975acc4bdec9...|2020-01-01 17:10:49|POINT (-73.267631...|0.7485722629444987|
|679ac975acc4bdec9...|2020-01-01 02:12:31|POINT (-73.271446...|0.7452303978930688|
|679ac975acc4bdec9...|2020-01-01 17:10:40|POINT (-73.265991...|0.7503403834426271|
|679ac975acc4bdec9...|2020-01-01 02:54:15|POINT (-73.271446...|0.7452310193408604|
|679ac975acc4bdec9...|2020-01-01 17:10:24|POINT (-73.265609...|0.7511492495935203|
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

How can I compute the distance from one point in a row to the following one?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, you want to collect the adjacent difference between rows in the `point` column. I believe you can accomplish this with a `lag` function (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) and a `Window` (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.Window):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, col
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("ID")
df = df.withColumn('distance', col('point') - lag(col('point')).over(window))
```